# page redirection after login

Tags: vue.js, vuex

below is vue.js2 code when user tries to login with credentials it should redirect to the dashboard view, however it does not get redirect even provided correct credentials:
and says can not rout to same page.

```
if (username && password) {
       const payload = { username, password };
       this.$store.dispatch(LOGIN,payload)
       .then((resp)=>{
         if(resp && resp.data.message==="Welcome" ) {
            this.error=false;
            console.log(this.$route.query)  // here it returns {} object
           this.$router.push(this.$route.query.redirect || "/");
         }
       })
        .catch(err => {
          this.error=true;
        console.log(err);
        });
```

EDIT Action LOGIN

```
[LOGIN]({commit}, payload) {
       // LOGIN user
        return loginService.LoginUser(payload).then(res => {
            const token = res.data.token;
            const user = res.data.userName
            localStorage.setItem('user', token)
            localStorage.setItem('token',user)
           //  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
            commit(AUTH_SUCCESS, token,user);
            return res;
        }).catch(error => {
            commit(AUTH_ERROR, error);
            localStorage.removeItem('token')
            localStorage.setItem('token',user)
        });
    },
```

//EDIT..ERROR

```
host-report-errors.js?44de:6 Unhandled promise rejection NavigationDuplicated {_name: "NavigationDuplicated", name: "NavigationDuplicated", message: "Navigating to current location ("/pages/login") is not allowed", stack: "Error↵    at new NavigationDuplicated (webpack-int…al:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:1862:57)"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a conditional:

```
if (
    this.$route.path !== '/' && 
    this.$route.path !== this.$route.query.redirect
) { 
    this.$router.push(this.$route.query.redirect || "/") 
}
```

As the error says, you can't route to the same route you're currently on.

Comment: No that did not worked at I think there has to be async issue here ?

Comment: please see my comments, just added in EDIT

Comment: Please see my original code, I have just updated it with EDIT section

Comment: yes every condition gets satisfied, it goes in and gives error on route

Comment: If the only error is about routing to the same page my answer should work. Try `this.$router.replace` instead

Comment: No it gives still same error, please see my original post I have added console error there.

Comment: If `this.$route.query.redirect` equals "/pages/login" `this.$router.push` wouldn't get called so there must be something wrong with the query